# How to overwrite authentication-popup.html in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, module

I need to overwrite **authentication-popup.html**. I need to add some extra html.

[image]

I just duplicated the authentication-popup.html file inside my module in the same folder from the default Magento module, but it didn't work.

[image]

There's some extra steps to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Customer/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html

Comment: If it's working for you accept this solution so another use same

Answer (score 2):

We have some ways to override this kind of html template.

**1) Override via XML (Recommended)**. If having a custom module already, we should use XML to override the template. I recommended this solution.

**Vendor/Customer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="authentication-popup">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="authenticationPopup" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Customer/authentication-popup</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Copy the content from the original file to our custom file:
**Vendor/Customer/view/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html**

Remember to clear Browser cache.

**2) Override via the custom theme**. If having a custom theme already, just simply copy the original file to our custom theme.

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Customer/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html*

**3) Override via require js:**

app/code/Vendor/Customer/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
          'Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html': 
              'Vendor_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html'
        }
  }
};
```

Comment: Option 3 is the only option I could get to work with these knockout-js html templates. They are different than regular .phtml templates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the correct path. In Google Chrome go into developer mode (F12 or CTRL + SHIFT + i), then "Network" and reload page. Then you can see exactly what file that you need to override. Just click on default.html and see the path

You can override it in your custom theme.

**Example :**

> MagentoDir/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/web/template/authentication-popup.html

In your custom theme the folder structure would be:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Custom_Theme/Magento_Customer/web/template/authentication-popup.html

After this run command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade